# Could not initialize GTK! Is DISPLAY env var/xhost set?

Tags: gtk, cygwin

I'm running GTKWave in cygwin but unfortunately i cannot open the UI and always point me to this error "Could not initialize GTK!  Is DISPLAY env var/xhost set?". Any one have an idea on what's happening here?., and btw i'm a complete beginner in cygwin.

Comment: http://wiki.tcl.tk/1866 ...start reading at "Are there any special add-on packages that would be useful when developing with Cygwin?"