# Cygwin/X WARNING **: Could not open X display

Tags: ssh, gtk, cygwin, x11, xorg

After opening cygwin with X, all works great and as expected, but after a few hours I can't open any other program that requires X display:

**from cygwin**

```
$ gnome-system-monitor 
** (gnome-system-monitor:21837): WARNING **: Could not open X display
(gnome-system-monitor:21837): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: localhost:10.0
```

**from spawned gnome-terminal**

```
$ gnome-terminal
** (gnome-terminal:20923): WARNING **: Could not open X display
Failed to parse arguments: Cannot open display:
```

other than that all works fine

## How to reproduce the error:

1. Install latest cygwin with all x11 components
2. run `ssh -X ${server}@${local-ip} -p${port}`
3. run `gui-command` (should work)
4. wait 1-2h (maybe less) and try to start an app with gui

the remote PC is running ubuntu with openssh

## Workaround:

Restart cygwin X server

I've looked into the official documentation and found [this](https://cygwin.com/faq.html#faq.using.bloda), but it is of no use as I don't seem to have any of that software installed, and the description of the problems are very broad.

## My questions:

What other workarounds are there? Are there others in the same situation? Did I do something wrong? Are there better ways to use remote X11 programs on windows?

Comment: And this should go to someone's bug tracker, not here. This isn't a question about programming.

Comment: sorry, but I don't know if it's a bug or if I misconfigured something

Comment: @DarkFalcon isn't this the same as : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20597770/could-not-initialize-gtk-is-display-env-var-xhost-set ? or did I write it wrong?

Comment: You have written it very well, I just don't think it belongs here. But that's my opinion. If 4 others agree, the question will be closed. Otherwise maybe someone will answer.

Comment: @DarkFalcon understood :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use -Y instead of -X. I had the same problem, this solved it.

Comment: I'll try, but what's the difference between `-Y` (Enable trusted X11 forwarding) and `-X` (Enable X11 forwarding) ?

Comment: nevermind, StackExchange had the answer : http://askubuntu.com/questions/35512/what-is-the-difference-between-ssh-y-trusted-x11-forwarding-and-ssh-x-u :)

Comment: The difference between `-X` and `-Y` is explained in the man page for `ssh` (`man ssh`)... 
` -Y      Enables trusted X11 forwarding.  Trusted X11 forwardings are not subjected to the X11 SECURITY
             extension controls.`